# dataGridView how to keep row number constant after filtering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with say 8 rows, and I filter for the values contained in rows 3, 4 and 5. That means that after I filter I would like to see rows 3, 4, 5 in the row headers. This could perhaps somehow be done if I set the the rowheader values to be constant?

**My current method of filtering is:**

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)Dgv.DataSource;
bs.Filter = string.Format(...);
Dgv.DataSource = bs;
```

**My current method of numbering rows is:**

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (SolidBrush b = new 
    SolidBrush(dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b,
        e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10,
        e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
    }
}
```

This paints the rowheaders, but whenever I filter they are numbered from the start again (1, 2, 3...).

If I set the row numbers in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dgv1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", i + 1);
}
```

then after the filtering I completely lose the values in the rowheaders. So I was thinking of perhaps giving the rowheaders a constant value on first loadup of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers start over again upon filtering because `e.RowIndex` will always run through the count of the `DataGridView.Rows` - which changes at time of filter.

Supposing your `BindingSource.DataSource` is a `DataTable`, you can achieve your goal by getting the index of the item from the non-filtered source:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rowItem = (DataRowView)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    int index = ((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataTable).Rows.IndexOf(rowItem.Row);

    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString((index + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b,
        e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10,
        e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
    }
}
```

If the underlying source is some other implementation of [`IBindingListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074142/3773066), then similarly you'll need to cast the row item and find it's index in the source collection:

```
var rowItem = (MyObject)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
int index = ((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource).IndexOf(rowItem);
```

The idea is: your items will be numbered according to their order in the main collection. When a filter is applied, the collection view changes, but the collection itself still contains all objects and therefore order - and your numbering - is unchanged.

Comment: Code worked well, I just had to handle a nullreference exception. That happened because when the datagridview gets populated it automatically adds one empty row in the end. In that case, DataBoundItem was null.

Comment: Glad you caught that - I had disabled `AllowUserToAddRows` so I missed it.