# What is the correct way to use Entity Framework as datasource for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I tried setting DataSource via DataGridView Designer but it wasn't listed there and then I generated new datasource via wizard which generated DataSet.

[image]

But now I have Entity Framework in my project + DataSet how can I use Entity Framework only... I'm confused.

`artiklBindingSource` was automatically generated I only wanted to use EF as datasource now I'm stuck with unwanted DataSet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To add a data source to use with your [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) in *DataGridView Tasks* panel, open *Choose Data Source:* combo box and then:

1. Click *Add Project Data Source* to open *Data Source Configuration Wizard*.
2. In *Choose a Data Source Type* Choose *Object* and click *Next*.
3. In *Select Data Source Objects* choose class which you want to add to data source and click *Finish*.
4. It will add a *BindingSource* to your *Form* which is used as *DataSource* of your *DataGridView* and you should load data and set data to *DataSource* of your *BindingSourc* and then data will be shown in your grid. For example to load data.

Here is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SampleDBEntities db;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new SampleDBEntities();
            db.Products.Load();
            this.productBindingSource.DataSource = db.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer, I always chose Database as Data Source and not Object I think this might be the thing that troubled me...

Comment: You may also want to just use "ToList" instead of "ToBindingList". Running faster for me and a binding list is created internally anyway. See this stackoverflow answer for the difference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages

Comment: How can a filter be applied to the entitylist, by field "ProductName" in example?

Comment: @Bull You may want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562593/3110834) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35978408/3110834).

Comment: Thank you very much, Reza!! Already saw those posts and others and found myself the soluction. Thumbs up!!

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it's the fastest method but it's the simpler:

```
dataGridViewStudents.DataSource = schoolContext.Students.ToList<Student>();
```

Comment: It will work but the `DbContext` cannot track changes that way, you should use 

`schoolContext.Students.Load();

dataGridViewStudents.DataSource = schoolContext.Students.Local.ToBindingList();
`