# Why is entity framework 6 not showing up datagridview binding wizard?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6, datasource

[Question asked by ChenChi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114690/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-entity-framework-as-datasource-for-datagridview)

I am trying to follow the steps in the answer that Reza Aghaei provided for ChenChi. I have created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my project in a subfolder named Models. I have a DataGridView object on my win form. In step 3 of Reza's answer, he states to choose a class. The Select the Data Objects dialog does not include the Models subfolder or its classes.

[Screen shot of data source configuration wizard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSGOM.jpg)

What am I missing?

Environment:

- Win 10 Enterprise
- VS 2017
- .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Build the project after adding the EF models.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you. The models did show up after the build.Now I just need to figure out the rest of the process to us EF.