# Editing textbox inside datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My project is c# windows form with Entity Framework , and I have DataGridView with a TextColumn. I want to edit the last column TextColumn Cells[3].
To get all values from database to GridView is not problem. I get them.
And I can put a new value but as soon as I click ontherplace then it changes to the old value. Textbox is not keeping the new value that I want to edit.
ReadOnly is false for this cells in column 3 becouse I can write but changes back the new value to the old values.
What kind of events I'am missing and how shall I do to fix this problem? By some how it seems like the hole Gridview is locked. Please Help.

I tried even:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
{   
   row.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false; 
}
```

Here below is my code.

```
private void Treatments_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
 try
            {
                using (MyHealthEntities db = new MyHealthEntities())
                { 
                    var  orderd = db.Order.Where(x => x.Ordernr == OrNr).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(orderd != null)
                    {
                        var myOrder = (from u in db.....
                                            join d in ...
                                            join m in ...
                                            where u.....
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                OrderId = m.MedId,
                                                Name = m. Name,
                                                Quality = m.Quality,
                                                Description = d.Description

                                            }
                                        ).ToList();
                        if (myOrder != null)
                        {


                            dgvOrder.DataSource = myOrder ;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
                    {   
                       row.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false; 
                    } 

                } 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

        }

}
```

Comment: I don't know Entity well enough, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117160/3585500) showing how to bind to a datagridview using Entity will help? It needs to be a BindingList and not just a List but the answer suggests it automatically converts to one when you bind to the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a normal System.Collections.Generic.List will not support editing when directly bound to because it does not implement IBindingList (or the necessary ListChanged event) for two-way data binding. You will likely need to wrap the List into a BindingList in order to edit the values. This will not be possible with an anonymous type.

First, create a class to store your List items:

```
public Class Order {
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Quality { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your query,

```
select new Order
{
    OrderId = m.MedId,
    Name = m. Name,
    Quality = m.Quality,
    Description = d.Description
}
```

Now move it to a BindingList:

```
if (myOrder != null) {
   BindingList<Order> myBindingList = New BindingList<Order>(myOrder);
   dgvOrder.DataSource = myBindingList;
}
```

I would also recommend wrapping the BindingList in a BindingSource, which will prevent you from having to handle rows being added/deleted manually:

```
if (myOrder != null) {
   BindingList<Order> myBindingList = New BindingList<Order>(myOrder);
   BindingSource myBindingSource = New BindingSource(myBindingList);
   dgvOrder.DataSource = myBindingSource;
}
```

Apologies if my syntax is a little off, I've been mostly using vb as of late.

**EDIT: I missed that BindingList does not implement IContainer, so the above code for binding to a BindingSource will not work because the single-parameter constructor for BindingSource specifically takes an IContainer.** If you still want to use a BindingSource, the third constructor of BindingSource should be used instead, like so:

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = New BindingSource(myBindingList, Nothing);
```

BindingSource does accept binding to an IBindingList, but only using this constructor or by directly setting the .DataSource property after using the parameterless constructor.
Leaving the erroneous code above so others who read OP's comment will understand what was being referenced.

Comment: Wonderfull. It's working without BindingSourse. If I use BindingSourse then  I get this error "cannot convert from 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Products.Orders.Order>' to 'System.ComponentModel.IContainer'"

Comment: Ah, glad we could get it working :) Edited my original comment to reflect the fact that BindingList cannot be wrapped in a BindingSource, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

**You can't edit DataGrid itens when you are using "dgvOrder.DataSource = myOrder".**

My suggestion is you do and "for each" in your myOrder list and add row by Row into Grid. After,  you can do an other "for each", recovery the datas from DataGrid and Save the itens in your db.Order.